# Problem with hotmail account, emails&contacts don't sync in any account

Tags: sync, email, outlook

I have a problem with new phone. (I'm using multiple phones almost all the time)
Problems start with LiveId (hotmail) account.
When I have entered the hotmail account credentials in phone setup, phone starts normally and everything seems to work fine. Except the hotmail sync, the synchronization never completes. It fetches some of my emails but not the latest ones. It seems to sync all the time, but never completing. Also no error is occuring. I also have other email accounts used in the phone and also none of these work completely, same story they sync but not completely.

I have tried restoring factory settings, unlinking everything (apps&accounts to my hotmail account). Removing Skype app etc. Nothing seems to make the problem go away.
Hardware is ok, because it works fine with some other liveId.

Also I tried removing the phone from 'my phones" in windowsphone.com"

The same hotmail account still works fine with my older phone. And I've had multiple windows phones in use at the same time for a long time already so it should not be about that.

Any clue what could be wrong with my hotmail account?